Looker Studio discrepancy. Control Dropdown
Data Connector: GSC.
I have created a new calculated field 'Resort' using the following regex_match
CASE
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/atherton-tablelands/.*")THEN "Atherton Tablelands"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/bairnsdale/.*")THEN "Bairnsdale"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/ballarat/.*")THEN "Ballarat"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/batemans-bay/.*")THEN "Batemans Bay"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/bathurst/.*")THEN "Bathurst"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/bowen-beachfront/.*")THEN "Bowen Beachfront"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/bright/.*")THEN "Bright"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/broulee/.*")THEN "Broulee"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/cairns/.*")THEN "Cairns"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/capricorn-yeppoon/.*")THEN "Capricorn Yeppoon"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/darlington-beach/.*")THEN "Darlington Beach"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/dubbo/.*")THEN "Dubbo"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/eastern-beach/.*")THEN "Eastern Beach"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/echuca/.*")THEN "Echuca"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/forster-tuncurry/.*")THEN "Forster Tuncurry"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/halls-gap/.*")THEN "Halls Gap"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/jindabyne/.*")THEN "Jindabyne"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/lake-somerset/.*")THEN "Lake Somerset"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/merimbula-beach/.*")THEN "Merimbula Beach"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/mildura-riverside/.*")THEN "Mildura Riverside"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/murramarang/.*")THEN "Murramarang"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/myall-shores/.*")THEN "Myall Shores"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/ocean-beach/.*")THEN "Ocean Beach"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/palm-cove/.*")THEN "Palm Cove"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/phillip-island/.*")THEN "Phillip Island"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/phillip-island/.*")THEN "Phillip Island"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/port-arthur/.*")THEN "Port Arthur"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/port-campbell/.*")THEN "Port Campbell"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/portland-bay/.*")THEN "Portland Bay"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/port-macquarie/.*")THEN "Port Macquarie"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/shellharbour-beachside/.*")THEN "Shellharbour Beachside"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/south-west-rocks/.*")THEN "South West Rocks"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/stockton-beach/.*")THEN "Stockton Beach"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/sydney-lakeside/.*")THEN "Sydney Lakeside"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/tathra-beachfront/.*")THEN "Tathra Beachfront"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/treasure-island/.*")THEN "Treasure Island"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/victor-harbor/.*")THEN "Victor Harbor"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/warrnambool-riverside/.*")THEN "Warrnambool Riverside"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/woodgate-beach/.*")THEN "Woodgate Beach"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, "(?i).*/yarrawonga-mulwala/.*")THEN "Yarrawonga Mulwala"
Else "no resort"
END

Now, when I use the above calculated _field as table filter OR Line Chart filter separately, it works fine. But when I try to use it as a control dropdown, it doesn't show the correct data, neither in the table nor in the line chart.
Please help.
I want to create a control dropdown to filter on the 'Resort' type data for line chart and table.
